# During uninstall third party application from control panel, I am getting this error. You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi, uninstallation, get-wmiobject

I am having script to uninstall **Veeam** software from control panel through PowerShell. While during uninstall of last the last Veeam components I am getting below error:

```
You Cannot call a method on a null-valued expression PowerShell : line 15 char:1
+ $console.Uninstall()
+ CategoryInfo         : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I have no idea, Experts help me to fix it. I am waiting for your reply. I have attached my script below.

```
function uninstallvm
{
$veeamConsole = 'Veeam Backup & Replication Console'
$objects = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product
$veeamComponents = $objects | where {$_.Name -like 'Veeam*' -and $_.Name -ne $veeamConsole}
foreach ($object in $veeamComponents) {
  Write-Output "Uninstalling $($object.Name)"
  $object.Uninstall()
}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$console = $objects | where {$_.Name -eq $veeamConsole}
Write-Output "Uninstalling $($console.Name)"
$console.Uninstall() 
}
uninstallvm
```

Comment: I would recommend filtering at the `Get-WmiObject` level to speed things up. `$objects = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product -Filter 'Name LIKE "%Veeam%"'` Might not make a huge difference, but that class can be a bit finicky.

Comment: As for your error, are you sure that the console is not uninstalled by the point it gets to that in the script? Perhaps some other component uninstalled it?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have filter like what you have suggested, but no luck. Still i am getting error in the same place. Yes all other components are uninstalled except the only one "Veeam Distribution Service". Can you please give me some idea to fix this issue. I am looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: The error you are getting is on `$console.Uninstall()`, which specifically is for 'Veeam Backup & Replication Console'. If that is uninstalled, and you're getting the error, then some other thing is removing it before your script gets to `$console.Uninstall()`. Run the `$objects = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product` line again after the `start-sleep -seconds 5` line, and I bet the error goes away.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you're getting that error is because after this:

```
$console = $objects | where {$_.Name -eq $veeamConsole}
```

Your `$console` variable is `$null` meaning that there was **no object** found with the **Name** property equal to ***Veeam Backup & Replication Console***:

```
PS /> $null.Uninstall()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $null.Uninstall()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

This could be easily fixed by adding a condition before trying to call the `uninstall` method.

```
function uninstallvm
{
    $veeamConsole = 'Veeam Backup & Replication Console'
    $objects = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product
    $veeamComponents = $objects | where {$_.Name -like 'Veeam*' -and $_.Name -ne $veeamConsole}
    
    foreach ($object in $veeamComponents)
    {
        Write-Output "Uninstalling $($object.Name)"
        $object.Uninstall()
    }
    
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    
    $console = $objects | where {$_.Name -eq $veeamConsole}
    
    if(-not $console)
    {
        return "No object found with name: $veeamConsole"
    }

    Write-Output "Uninstalling $($console.Name)"
    $console.Uninstall() 
}

uninstallvm
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I don't know how to adding a condition before trying to call the uninstall. What condition I have to exactly add, I have no idea. Can you please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: @jimmyafflick I already fixed it for you, check the code where it says `if(-not $console){ ... }`

Comment: Thanks much  for your reply let me check it